# how to send HMAC SHA 256 Secret key to binance api?

Tags: api, key, hmac, binance

I write this code:

```
api_key = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/myTrades??X-MBX-APIKEY="+config.API_Key+"&signature="+config.Secret_Key
```

and get this error:

```
{"code":-2014,"msg":"API-key format invalid."}
```

and this the documentation of binance api
https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#endpoint-security-type

Comment: one question mark is extra i correct that and still get error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `X-MBX-APIKEY` as a request header, not as a GET param.

Unfortunately your code doesn't show how you build the request, but here's an example using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios):

```
axios({
    url: 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/myTrades',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
        'X-MBX-APIKEY': config.API_Key
    }
}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
})
```